# Java EE suitablity for a social network using Cassandra datastore?

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, web-applications, ejb, cassandra

We are in the process of making some important technology decisions for a social networking application. We're planning to have Cassandra(a NoSQL database to support efficient data storage).
We would be using Hector(a Java client) to interact with Cassandra.

**1.) Would Java EE be a good choice over PHP for a social networking application in terms of performance, scalabilty & complexities?**

**2.) Another possible implementation strategy, Is it suitable to have backend alone in Java and rest in PHP?**

**3.) What differences(as compared to PHP) it makes in terms of costs at various stages of application development, deployment and maintenance ?**

**4.) What are the things to keep in mind as we move along with Java development& deployment(as we are relatively new to the Java background) ?**

**5.) If you could list some major production deployments of similar type(social network) applications in Java.**

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of application almost doesn't matter for your question. You can write a complex web app in PHP. You can write it in Java EE. By far, the largest component to choosing the appropriate architecture is capabilities of your team. If you have a crack team of PHP coders, you are likely to loose a lot of money pursuing a Java EE architecture and end up with a sub-par solution. Conversely, if you have a crack team of Java EE developers, pushing PHP on them isn't going to improve their productivity or yield a better application.

Either technology is capable when well-applied in doing what you are contemplating.

Comment: well said Konstantin but I know both technologies are capable that's why they are eligible for this question. What I mean to ask is what provides a much better solution for my particular case in terms of performance, scalabilty & also the complexities involved during development, deployment and maintenance. Suppose you have the limited manpower in a small startup(that knows both Java & PHP) which would be more prefered over the other ?

Comment: Hmm... That seems to be contradict your statements in the question. In particular #3. If your team is new to Java EE and has more experience in PHP development, I wouldn't recommend pushing Java EE approach. You can get comparable performance and scalability from either PHP or Java EE. One doesn't have an inherent advantage over the other. Anything you hear to the contrary is inherent bias/preference of the person.

Answer (score 2):

Answering your last question: if i remember correctly linkedin is almost entirely written java (with spring).